# How to sort a svydesign object?

Tags: r, survey

I need to sort in ascending order the SCF multiply imputed dataset in R by a specific (numeric) variable. Since I'm working with a svydesign object (containing a list of five implicates from the SCF ) in R, it didn't work to use the function sort or order as we usually do with data.frames.
Does anybody know how to do this in R?

Thank u for your help!

Comment: Please share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: could you clarify why you want to sort a multiply-imputed design?  not sure if sorting individual implicates screws up the replicate weights in this design  http://asdfree.com/survey-of-consumer-finances-scf.html   `

Comment: Hello, Mr. @AnthonyDamico, Thank you for your answer. I need to subset  the dataset from 0 to 1% , 1% to 5% , 5 to 10% and 0 to 20% quantiles, but all this households have earnings=0.  Kuhn & Rios-Rull (2015) used income as a second dimension for sorting households. So, i need to sort by earnings, then by income, finally i need to subset the sample.

Comment: scf data has households with nonzero earnings..sounds like you might be trying to create a categorical variable rather than sort?  perhaps find cutoffs with the `svyquantile` line from the link above and use those thresholds to create a new variable with `scf_design <- update( scf_design , categorical_variable = findInterval( linear_variable , c( cutoff1 , cutoff2 , cutoff3 ) )`

Comment: Thank you so much Mr @AnthonyDamico, your answer helped me to solve my problem. Have a nice week-end.